# How to loop through colors?

Tags: unity, c#

I want to loop between two color in unity

```
public float speed = 1.0f;
public Color startColor;
public Color endColor;
public bool repeatable = false;
float startTime;

// Use this for initialization
void Start()
{
    startTime = Time.time;
}

// Update is called once per frame
void Update()
{
    if (!repeatable)
    {
        float t = (Time.time - startTime) * speed;
        GetComponent<Light>().color = Color.Lerp(startColor, endColor, t);
    }
    else
    {
        float t = (Mathf.Sin(Time.time - startTime) * speed);
        GetComponent<Light>().color = Color.Lerp(startColor, endColor, t);
    }
}
```

Comment: What is your endgoal here?

Comment: I want to loop between two color red and blue ;

Comment: You want to ping pong between 2 color values?

Comment: and my end goal is change the color  of point light gradually with time and loop the colors

Answer (score 3):

Use [Mathf.PingPong](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Mathf.PingPong.html) to lerp between your colors

```
private float duration = 5 ;
private Light lightComponent ;

private void Awake()
{
    lightComponent = GetComponent<Light>();
}

void Update()
{
    float t1 = Mathf.PingPong(Time.time - startTime, 1) / duration;
    float t2 = (Mathf.Cos( ( (Time.time - startTime) + duration ) * Mathf.PI / duration ) + 1 ) * 0.5f

    // Use t2 instead of t1 if you want smoother interpolation
    lightComponent.color = Color.Lerp(startColor, endColor, t1);
}
```

[Desmos plot showing t2](https://www.desmos.com/calculator/0obcbjygjb)